# moveit_commander_cmdline.py Error

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, moveit-commander

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I was going through the `Moveit` tutorials here: [Moveit Commander Scripting](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/moveit_commander_scripting/moveit_commander_scripting_tutorial.html) and when I tried launching `rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py`, I am getting the following error:

```
kashyap@kashyap-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$ rosrun moveit_commander moveit_commander_cmdline.py
Failed to import pyassimp, see https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/86 for more info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/bin/moveit_commander_cmdline.py", line 156, in <module>
    run_interactive(opt.group_name)
  File "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/bin/moveit_commander_cmdline.py", line 81, in run_interactive
    c = MoveGroupCommandInterpreter()
  File "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/interpreter.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._planning_scene_interface = PlanningSceneInterface()
  File "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/moveit/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/planning_scene_interface.py", line 62, in __init__
    self._psi = _moveit_planning_scene_interface.PlanningSceneInterface()
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    PlanningSceneInterface.__init__(PlanningSceneInterface)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
```

Could anyone guide me as to what this error means? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292829/moveit_commander_cmdline.py-error/) by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known problem, and there is already a PR to fix it: [ros-planning/moveit#929](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/929).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-06-04**:
Thanks, the fix worked